# Function using alias

Tags: c++, c++11, using

What exactly does the following code declare;

```
using f1 = void(int);
```

I know that the following;

```
using f2 = void(*)(int);
using f3 = void(&)(int);
```

`f2` is a pointer to a function and `f3` would be the reference.

Comment: f1 is the function itself. (f1, f2 and f3 are all types, so properly "f1 is a type of a function").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is it?

It's a *function type*. When you declare a function, such as:

```
void func(int);
```

its type is not a pointer nor a reference. The above function's type is `void(int)`.

We can "prove" it by using *type traits* as follows:

```
void func(int) {}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(func), void(int)>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(func), void(*)(int)>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(func), void(&)(int)>::value << '\n';
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ded7d25d4442c4e)

The above code will return `true` only for the first row.

### Is it the same as a pointer or a reference?

No, but a function lvalue can be implicitly converted to a function pointer as per:

> **§4.3/1 Function-to-pointer conversion [conv.func]**
>
> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the function.

The relationship between a function type `A(Args...)` and its reference (namely `A(&)(Args...)`) is basically the same as the relationship between any type `T` and its reference (namely `T&`).

### Where's it used?

It's often used as a template parameter.

For example `std::function` takes a function type to be stored inside the `std::function` object and you can declare such an object with:

```
std::function<void(int)> fn;
```

Comment: I found the code snippet relating to the `decltype` particularly useful.

Answer (score 3):

It declares `f1` to be a function type, with an `int` parameter and no return type.

It's equivalent to the old-school declaration

```
typedef void f(int);
```